# Mapping shapefile attributes to raw data

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have raw address data stored in a sql server database (2012) which comprises address, city/suburb, state and generally country (Australia).  I would like to take this address data and following geocoding to long/lat coordinates, match these points to a respective shapefile containing administrative boundary data/polygons.  My aim is to add columns to my address data from attributes from the shapefile e.g. LGA_NAME for the purpose of mapping within reporting tools like report builder 3 or Tableau.  I have a copy of QGIS I am experimenting with but haven't found a way to do what I want as yet.

I suspect this would be a fairly straightforward task and the point in polygon concept suggests it should be possible.

I have looked for a suitable tutorial for this but am yet to find anything.

Can anyone help?